# Using structs and arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct

This here is a small portion of a larger program I need to create to enter songs and their info into a database. I am new to using structs and my professor hasnt showed us yet on how to pass structs into functions and then using those inside main. I am also not supposed to use pointers yet. I get many errors when compiling and I'm not sure where to start.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct mp3song_struct {
    char title[40];
    char artist1[20];
    char artist2[20];
    char artist3[20];
    int datemonth;
    int dateday;
    int dateyear;
    char genre[10]; 

}mp3song;

void populate(mp3song totalsongs[30]);

int main() {

struct mp3song totalsongs[30];

populate(mp3song totalsongs);


}

void populate(mp3song totalsongs[30]){

int i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    printf("Enter song title: \n");
    scanf("%c", &totalsongs[i].title);
    printf("Enter Artists(If no more than 1 enter \"none\")");
    printf("Enter artist: \n");
    scanf("%c", &totalsongs[i].artist1);
    printf("Enter artist: \n");
    scanf("%c", &totalsongs[i].artist2);
    printf("Enter artist: \n");
    scanf("%c", &totalsongs[i].artist3);
    printf("Ente date mm/dd/yyyy\n");
    printf("Enter month: \n");
    scanf("%d", &totalsongs[i].datemonth);
    printf("Enter day: \n");
    scanf("%d", &totalsongs[i].dateday);
    printf("Enter year: \n");
    scanf("%d", &totalsongs[i].dateyear);
    printf("Enter genre: \n");
    scanf("%c", &totalsongs[i].genre);
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't modify your code in question with solution, it will not be in syn with answer, and your question description

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code. You can declare `int populate(struct mp3song, struct mp3song totalsongs[30]);` as `void populate(struct mp3song, struct mp3song totalsongs[30]);` since you are not returning an integer.

mp3song is not an array so it cannot be subscripted like &mp3song[i]. In fact populate function cannot receive `struct mp3song` as it is a type not value. So modify `populate` function line `int populate(struct mp3song totalsongs[30]);` and then replace all occurances of `&mp3song[i]` with `&totalsongs[i]` and you will be able to take input in the array.

Comment: Ok i edited code and made a couple other revisions based on error messages, see above. But im still left with                                                 $ gcc hw8.c
hw8.c: In function ‘main’:
hw8.c:19:16: error: array type has incomplete element type
 struct mp3song totalsongs[30];
                ^
hw8.c:21:10: error: expected expression before ‘mp3song’
 populate(mp3song totalsongs);
          ^

Comment: You should call `populate(struct mp3song totalsongs);`

Answer (score 0):

1. `mp3song` is a `structure name` not `structure variable`
2. you need to declare a variable of that structure type to pass a structure.

example:

```
struct definition
struct <struct_name>{

Struct elements;
}<struct variable>;


struct <struct_name> <struct_variable>;
```

In your case
you can pass only variable not struct_name

```
struct mp3song totalsongs[30];
populate(totalsongs[30]);
```

function definition

```
<return_type int or void> populate(struct mp3song totalsongs[30]);
```

Now you can access structure elements with variable name totalsongs inside the function.

modifed code of yours

```
 #include <stdio.h>

typedef struct mp3song {
    char title[40];
    char artist1[20];
    char artist2[20];
    char artist3[20];
    int datemonth;
    int dateday;
    int dateyear;
    char genre[10];

};

void populate(struct mp3song totalsongs[30]);

int main() {

struct mp3song totalsongs[30];

populate(totalsongs);


}
void populate(struct mp3song totalsongs[30]){

int i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    printf("Enter song title: \n");
    scanf("%s", &totalsongs[i].title);
    printf("Enter Artists(If no more than 1 enter \"none\")");
    printf("Enter artist: \n");
    printf("TITLE: : %s \n",totalsongs[i].title);
    scanf("%c", &totalsongs[i].artist1);
    printf("Enter artist: \n");
    scanf("%c", &totalsongs[i].artist2);
    printf("Enter artist: \n");
    scanf("%c", &totalsongs[i].artist3);
    printf("Ente date mm/dd/yyyy\n");
    printf("Enter month: \n");
    scanf("%d", &totalsongs[i].datemonth);
    printf("Enter day: \n");
    scanf("%d", &totalsongs[i].dateday);
    printf("Enter year: \n");
    scanf("%d", &totalsongs[i].dateyear);
    printf("Enter genre: \n");
    scanf("%c", &totalsongs[i].genre);
}
}
```

Comment: The compiler doesnt like the fact mp3song totalsongs[30] is being declared as struct in void populate(struct mp3song totalsongs[30]). And also I keep getting error of  error: array type has incomplete element type
 struct mp3song totalsongs[30];
                ^

Comment: @JoeRiefski use the code which I shared in my answer and try.

Comment: ok it complies however when I input data it will skip entering the dates and it will start the loop over again.

Comment: Change %c to %s and add space before %s like " %s"

Comment: ok when i input data that has a space in it, it enters the second word as the next input. Example: Artist-Bob Smith becomes Artist-Bob Artist-Smith. I think i recall this happens if you enter a space while doings strings but is there a way around this?

Comment: It won't consider space as input

Comment: @JoeRiefski you can try this %[^\n]s instead of %s